# Restlet createQuery fails with connection error (and after workaround NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: android, odata, restlet

I followed the Android [restlet tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/archive/2011/09/13/accessing-odata-from-android-using-restlet.aspx) and tried to consume a sample OData webservice (http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/).  When I create a query with `myService.createProductQuery("/Products");` logcat tells me that

> ERROR/org.restlet(700): Can't get the metadata for ...

A problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308243/restlet-cant-get-the-data-with-android).  I did try and register the Apache client as suggested by Jerome Louvel:

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().clear();
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().add(new HttpClientHelper(null));
```

Unfortunately I get a new error. On Query initialization I get a NoSuchMethodError exception.  The Query class seems to want to call MyService.getMetadatada().  From the docs I see this is a protected method on org.restlet.ext.odata.Service

Happens on version 2.0.11 and 2.1rc3 of Restlet.

Additionally I also tried a home-made .NET 4.0 WCF webservice, with the same results.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers that come upon this question: just make double sure your Manifest file sets permission on your application to access the internet. (For shame).  Obviously it needs access to the network to "call" the webservice.

```
..
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```